# googleapis revokeCredentials not returning a result in successful callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

According to the [test suite](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/test/test.auth.js#L215) the callback function passed to `revokeCredentials` gets a result object if the operation was successful which should contain a `success` property. However, when I  use this snippet:

```
oauth2client.revokeCredentials(function (error, result) {
  if (error || !result.success) {
    console.error('Failed to revoke credentials!');
    console.error(error || result);
  } else {
    //...
  }
});
```

I get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined` - am I missing something?

[Copied from issue #445](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/445)

Comment: I also have a tangentially related question: if you have the refresh token, do you have to have a valid access token to call `revokeCredentials`? It seems like overkill to me to have to call `refreshAccessToken` before calling this just to be sure...

Comment: I run into this issue too :(